React setState of the last object in the array state
i have array of objects state that hold users objects, when user clicks add button it adds a new empty object to the state
setUsers([...users, newRow]);


when user upload image i want to add the image file to that object:
<input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={(e) => setUsers([...users, lastObject.image:e.target.files[0]])} />

how to get the image property of the last object in the state and set it ?

import React, { useState } from 'react';  
    
const App = () => {  
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);  
    const handleUser = () => {  
        setUsers([...users, {}]);
    };  
    
    const handleImageUpload = (e) => {  
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        if (!file) return;
    
        const newUsers = [...users];
        newUsers[newUsers.length - 1] = {
            ...newUsers[newUsers.length - 1],
            image: file,           
      };  
    return (  
        <div>  
          <button onClick={handleUser}>Add User</button>  
          <input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={handleImageUpload} />
        </div>  
    );  
};  
    
export default App;  

Please try with this. Hope you any help. Thanks.
